# How to change the wordpress add media popup to list view instead of grid

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress website, my images are large in size, some up to 25MB, now when I want to add media to a post or a custom post type, the popup takes forever to load images. Is there a way to change this to list view instead of the default grid or perhaps reduce the number of media files loaded up? Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to

[image: Add media popup]